# Structuring templates in an AngularJS SPA - are there performance issues when using ng-include a lot?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I was wondering what the best way to structure templates in an AngularJS SPA. So far I have kind of a rails approach, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

What I mean is that I for example have a `/js/app/views/partials` folder where I have snippets of html that are used in different places. This could be a form or a preview of content, basically everything that is used all over the app. I like this structure because let's say you have a comment form that appears in 5 different places and you want to add a field: Changing one file rather than 5 is much better.

I then for example have a `/js/app/views/home.html` template, that is referenced by my ui-router and loaded in ui-view in `/index.html` which only serves as layout.

**/js/app/routes.js**

```
myModule.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/js/app/views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
          // resolve code
        }
     });
  }
]);
```

**/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title><%= title %></title>

    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css' />

    <script src="/js/angularjs-1.3.16.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-ui-router-0.2.15.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app/routes/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app/services/services.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**/js/app/views/home.html**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>v2</h1>
</div>

<div ng-include src="'/js/app/views/partials/post-form.html'"></div>

<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <div ng-include src="'/js/app/views/partials/post-preview.html'"></div>
</div>
```

So the ui-router is called with the `home` state and injects the `/js/app/views/home.html` in `/index.html` (at ui-view). `home.html` itself includes two partials `/js/app/views/partials/post-form.html` and `/js/app/views/partials/post-preview.html`.

The result are a lot of XHR requests for a single page load. That cannot be good for performance.

Is there a better way to do that? Or can I just not structure my views with so many partials and have to use fewer files and repetitive code?

My backend / server is NodeJS with Express. So maybe it would also be an option to do that server-side, using express partials.

Comment: Did your profiling show any performance bottlenecks? Initial loads might be high, but during the lifetime of the app angular caches the html templates loaded by ng-include, see [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

Comment: Yes, the app already reacts a bit slower. Also see this arcitle: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2738-using-ngrepeat-with-nginclude-hurts-performance-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: I just also discovered this post which seems to be quite useful for this topic: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9559